# Jquery Defered.resolve don't pass parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I have promise as following code. After I have resolved promise with parameter,
I  want to get parameter  in done() method.

```
function splitAndSetTebiskopUrl(tebiskopUrl){
    splits = tebiskopUrl.split("\u0007");
    tebiskopUrl = splits[0];
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    if(splits[1]){
        var cookieValue = splits[1];

        return $.ajax({
            type:'POST', 
            url:'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 
            data:{'cookieValue':cookieValue},

        }).then(function(data){
            if(data && data.cookieValue){
                defer.resolve(tebiskopUrl);

            }else{
                defer.reject("cookie value doesn't exist");
            }
        },
          function(){
            defer.reject("tebiskopCookieSet request error");
        });

    }else{
        defer.resolve(tebiskopUrl);
    }

    return defer.promise(); 
}
```

The parameter is not passed to done() method. Unfortunetly I get it as undefined. I have looked a lot of example. But I can't find the problem.

```
splitAndSetTebiskopUrl(url).done(function(parameter){
                //parameter is undefined
             });
```

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Bergi  What can I use  other. Can you give example ? . I have two condition. In first condition , we have to wait ajax result and In second condition , without ajax I have to return given parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `if` block, you are `return`ing the promise from the chained `then` call - the promise of the `defer` that you resolve will not be returned here. You could just omit that `return` keyword and the code would work, but really you should avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and indeed simply return the promise from the chain:

```
function splitAndSetTebiskopUrl(tebiskopUrl){
    var splits = tebiskopUrl.split("\u0007");
    tebiskopUrl = splits[0];
    if (splits[1]) {
        return $.ajax({
            type:'POST', 
            url:'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 
            data:{'cookieValue': split[1]},
        }).then(function(data){
            if (data && data.cookieValue) {
                return tebiskopUrl;
            } else {
                throw new Error("cookie value doesn't exist");
            }
        }, function(err) {
            throw new Error("tebiskopCookieSet request error");
        });
    } else {
        return $.when(tebiskopUrl);
    }
}
```